# How to send a text message via AT+CMGS?

Tags: linux, adb, at-command, modem, cellular-network

I am testing different AT commands including the one used for sending a text message, which is `AT+CMGS`.

From what I've read online, you just need to provide a phone number as shown below and enter CTRL-Z to send a message but nothing really happens when I press CTRL-Z

```
echo -e "AT+CMGS='"<phone_number>"'"\r" > /dev/<port>
> Sending message...
<PRESS CTRL-Z but nothing happens>
```

Comment: Hard to know how to test a cellular connection. Are you sure about the arrangment of dbl and single quotes in your `echo -e` line? I count dbl-quotes that aren't an even number (which I would normally expect). Just some ideas. Good luck!

Comment: I'd also recommend that you make literal your inputs. Using `<>` chars in example data leads to worries about "is the OP using a template found someplace?" . I'd recommend trying `port=999; phone_num=3125274333 ; echo -e "AT_CMGS='$phone_num'\r" > /dev/"$port"`. Of course for your testing, use real values for `port` and `phone_num`, Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, after sending characters to your port with `echo -e`, you also get the output from your serial port with

```
cat /dev/<port> &
```

so that every answer from the modem is automatically redirected to your console.

In this case, the character `>` doesn't mean you can *directly* send the text; you'll have to go on sending it with `echo -e`. Here is the sequence of commands, with some comments on the right that obviously don't have to be included

```
echo -e "AT+CMGS='"<phone_number>"'"\r" > /dev/<port>  // Command
>                                                      // Modem's response
echo -e "My text!\x1A" > /dev/<port>                   // Send text

+CMGS: XYZ                                             // Response to SMS sending
OK                                                     // It can take several seconds
```

Please note how binary data is sent through `\xAB` escape sequence, where `AB` is the ASCII value of the character you want to append. More info on the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo).

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I tried using `echo` after sending the command to no avail...I don't see a response to my text message and neither I get CTRL-Z to work

Comment: also, doesn't adding `&` at the end of the command runs stuff in the background and doesn't print it to console?

Comment: @Jazzy, I confirm that `&` runs in background in order to have the console "free" to send firther commands. However, the output of the command is printed anyway to stdout. Do you see output to _any_ command? What if you provide `echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/port`?